# How to refresh Grid when I add element in List - Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor

I have one list to make bind, i add elements to list but i cannot show items in Grid.

I have this code:

public List list= new List() { };
list.Add(new Test() {name = "xpto"} );

```
public class Test
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
}

<SfGrid DataSource="@list">
     <GridColumns>
       <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Test.name) HeaderText="Name"</GridColumn>
     </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>
```

But i got nothing in SfGrid.

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/152714/grid-refresh-state

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing the **GridColumns** element:

```
<SfGrid DataSource="@list">
     <GridColumns>
         <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Test.name) HeaderText="Name"></GridColumn>
     </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>
```

Comment: in my case i have GridColumns

Comment: Not sure what you mean - In the code you have shown the element is missing. If you added it and it still doesn't work then update the question with the new code.

Comment: My problem is how to refresh Grid automaticly when I insert a new element in list.